# AVPlayer slow loading from server

Tags: ios, iphone, video, video-streaming, avplayer

I use AVPlayer to play .MOV videos stored on my dedicated server.
When an user wants to play a video, i load it on AVPlayer using a direct link like this : "wwww.myserver.com/videos/video.mov".
(I don't use php file, maybe i should..)

Generally videos take 1-2 seconds to start playing, but sometimes it can be very slow(until 1 minutes)
However, **once the video started, the loading is very quick, but the start can be long, very long (even with fast connection).**
Videos are small (maximum 6Mo), i compressed them using [SDAVAssetExportSession](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession).
Also I've disabled App Transport Security.

The issue can be server side ? i really don't know how solve this problem

Any help is appreciated

**edit 1** : [link to video on my server](http://www.appscenes.fr/videos/video_test.mov)

Comment: Url to your video on the server can be helpful. Looks like the issue is in the server and not in AVPlayer.